# Return multiple "while" loop results

Tags: python, list, loops, while-loop

I have a while loop that returns data to a function.

```
    while (count < int(pagecount)):
        count = count + 1
        request = requestGet("http://www.site.com/User.aspx?ID={0}&page={1}".format(self.userid, count))
        regexdata = re.findall('REGEX" REGEX="(.*?)"', request)
        return regexdata
```

I need to know how I can return each value back to the function the while loop is in. Also, to be more specific, the data that I'm returning is actually in a list. So maybe somehow appending the new list to the old list would be a better approach. Either way, I'm lost and I need help.

Thanks.

Comment: "return each value back to the function the while loop is in…" is exactly what generators are for. See the [Iterators](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#iterators) and subsequent two sections in the tutorial for an explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to return a bunch of things, put them in a list and return that:

```
results = []
while (count < int(pagecount)):
    count = count + 1
    request = requestGet("http://www.site.com/User.aspx?ID={0}&page={1}".format(self.userid, count))
    regexdata = re.findall('REGEX" REGEX="(.*?)"', request)
    results.append(regexdata)
return results
```

Alternatively, it might be appropriate to `yield` the results, turning your function into a generator:

```
while (count < int(pagecount)):
    count = count + 1
    request = requestGet("http://www.site.com/User.aspx?ID={0}&page={1}".format(self.userid, count))
    regexdata = re.findall('REGEX" REGEX="(.*?)"', request)
    yield regexdata
```

Both of these options let you iterate over the return value to get the elements, but the generator option only lets you do so once. `return` halts the function immediately, so once your function hits a `return`, it won't continue on to further loop iterations.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [Generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators):

```
def getRegexData(self):     
    while (count < int(pagecount)):
        count = count + 1
        request = requestGet("http://www.site.com/User.aspx?ID={0}&page={1}".format(
                            self.userid, count))
        yield re.findall('REGEX" REGEX="(.*?)"', request)
```